# Microsoft Excel detect user clearing cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that checks a cell once it has been changed and formats the input of that cell to an accepted format. This was done to make it easier for the user by allowing them to be able to input the data in multiple ways and have the cell come out correctly.

I have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set rCells = Range("C3:C4, G9:G24, C60:C61, G66:G81")
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Application.Intersect(rCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
            Format(Range(Target.Address))
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

...to catch the change and then format the input to the correct format.

I want the user however to be able to leave the cell blank.

What can I add to this block to allow the user to clear a cell using DEL or BACKSPACE without triggering format()?

I have tried:

```
If IsEmpty(Target) Then Exit Sub
```

But that doesn't seem to do it.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: 1) you can use `Format(Target)` instead `Format(Range(Target.Address))` 2) I suggest you to change name of your function `Format` since there is built in funcition with this name. 3) `Target` is always single-cell range or it can be multiply-cells range?

Comment: Thank you for the Format(Target) tip, I changed that and it is working properly. The potential name conflict you point out isnt really an issue though, the code I put here is kind of a modified snippet with relevant info only. The real code has 5 different format functions named <type>_format.

Comment: what about my third question: `Target is always single-cell range or it can be multiply-cells range`?

Comment: Oh, usually it will be only 1 cell. I wrote it to allow for multiple cells though because the end-users I am working with are not quite tech-savvy and my boss wanted me to make it as "bulletproof" as possible.

Comment: try to add this line `If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Target) = Target.Cells.Count Then Exit Sub`, let me know if it helps:)

Comment: Thats it! That did exactly what i wanted it to do. Thank You! now please post that as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this line to check whether all cell in `Target` range are empty:

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Target) = Target.Cells.Count Then Exit Sub
```

also as I mentioned in comments

- change `Format(Range(Target.Address))` to `Format(Target)`
- don't forget to change function name `Format` in real code to something like `My_Format` since there is built-in function with this name:)

Answer (score 0):

Test for **=""**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub
    Set rCells = Range("C3:C4, G9:G24, C60:C61, G66:G81")
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Not Intersect(rCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
            Format (Target)
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: When i add this line then press delete on the cell I get the error: "type mismatch" pointing to that line